# Convert Typed List in Groovy to String List

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to change a typed list into a string list. I'm using the AWS SDK to get a list of PackageVersionResponse objects and I want to create a String list of the version method:

```
def client = AWSCodeArtifactClientBuilder.standard()
  .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
  .withRegion(region)
  .build()
def lpm = ListPackageVersionsRequest().builder(domain)
      .repository(repo)
      .packageValue(package)
def pvs = client.ListPackageVersions(params)
// change pvs into String list of return value of version method
```

In node I'd do something like `pvs.map(pv => pv.version())` and get a String array of versions, but I'm not sure what the equivalent is in Groovy / Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should just be

```
def pvs = client.listPackageVersions(params).versions.collect { it.version }
```

Or using the spread operator

```
def pvs = client.listPackageVersions(params).versions*.version
```

(from tracing the javadoc for the [client method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/codeartifact/AWSCodeArtifact.html#listPackageVersions-com.amazonaws.services.codeartifact.model.ListPackageVersionsRequest-), the [ListPackageVersionsResult](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/codeartifact/model/ListPackageVersionsResult.html) object and the [getVersion method inside the PackageVersionSummary class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/codeartifact/model/PackageVersionSummary.html))

Comment: Thanks, I was sure it'd be simple. I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm back in work tomorrow to test it.

Comment: Fingers crossed it works! Have an awesome night